# Systems of differential equations and spectral theory.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, spectral-theory

Say that we have the system of differential equations in matrix formulation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    C(t) \\
    C_p(t)
\end{bmatrix}'
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -k_{cp}-k_{ce} & k_{pc} \\
    k_{cp} & - k_{pc}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    C(t) \\
    C_p(t)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    k_aF \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}e^{-k_at},\;\;\;\;
\begin{bmatrix}
    C(0) \\
    C_p(0)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I have been given the solution to $C(t)$:
$$
C(t)=\frac{Fk_aB}{k_a-\lambda}\left(e^{-\lambda t} - e^{-k_a t}\right) + \frac{Fk_aC}{k_a-\mu}\left(e^{-\mu t} - e^{-k_a t}\right),\;\; B, C \in \mathbb{R}\;\;\;\;\; (1)
$$
where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the eigenvalues to

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
    -k_{cp}-k_{ce} & k_{pc} \\
    k_{cp} & - k_{pc}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What I want to do is to somehow determine $k_{cp}$, $k_{pc}$, $k_{ce}$ if I am given equation 1.
I know that
$$
\lambda+\mu = \text{Tr} A =-k_{cp}-k_{pc}-k_{ce},\\
\mu\lambda = \text{det} A=k_{ce}k_{pc}. 
$$
My problem is that I need a third equation to be able to solve for $k_{cp}$, $k_{pc}$, $k_{ce}$, but I am not really sure how I can find one more equation. Thanks!

Edit: to be extra clear, say that I have a specific solution and I know all the values of the constans in equation (1). I am seeking a system of equations that out of which I can determine $k_{cp}$, $k_{pc}$, $k_{ce}$ given the solution.

Comment: You do not need an extra equation, you just have more degrees of freedom, this is it. Also, the trace is equal to the sum of the negatives of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @KBS. Ok, I am told to find a third equation by my teacher, which is why I am asking this question

Comment: Then, either you invent one or you create one that makes sense for your problem at hand.